# Local variable might be referenced before assignment

Tags: python

This working function will receive a dictionary that will proceed with uploading or download files based on the transfer_type value. But currently my IDE is displaying the warning`Local variable  might be referenced before assignment` when i'm using it to execute  the `subprocess.run` stage.

My question is, should i accept the sugestion of declating as a global variable inside the function ( `global cmd` ) or should I ignore this suggestion?

```
def scp_transfer(data):

    host = data['host']
    remote = data['remote']
    local = data['local']
    transfer_type = data['transfer_type']

    if transfer_type == 'download':
        cmd = 'scp -qr %s:%s %s' % (host, remote, local)
    if transfer_type == 'upload':
        cmd = 'scp -qr %s %s:%s' % (local, host, remote)

    run = subprocess.run(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    try:
        run.check_returncode()
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        print(e.output)
    else:
        print(run.stdout.decode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: The warning refers to the possibility that `cmd` doesn't exist. Is there any possibility that `transfer_type` is not either 'download' or 'upload'?

Comment: Forget the global variable; you should throw an exception if `transfer_type` isn't "upload" or "download".

Comment: No, `global cmd` is really not the answer here.  It's setting `cmd` to a known value at some point along the way, or having good error handling and exiting before the `subprocess.run()` call if `transfer_type` is not `'upload'` or `'download'`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would avoid declaring it as a `global`. You could declare it within the function:

```
cmd = None
if transfer_type == 'download':
    cmd = 'scp -qr %s:%s %s' % (host, remote, local)
if transfer_type == 'upload':
    cmd = 'scp -qr %s %s:%s' % (local, host, remote)
```

This could still cause issues when you try to run the `cmd` though. Instead, you should raise an exception if `transfer_type` doesn't match anything.

```
if transfer_type == 'download':
    cmd = 'scp -qr %s:%s %s' % (host, remote, local)
elif transfer_type == 'upload':
    cmd = 'scp -qr %s %s:%s' % (local, host, remote)
else:
    raise ValueError('Unexpected transfer type: %s' % transfer_type)
```

In any case, I would always pay attention to the warning.

Comment: ) is missing from the last line, but i can't edit it.

Comment: @thclpr Thanks, I switched to old formatting to match OP's code too.